# How to utilize variable in string parameter for a function call

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create text files each different in respect to the ending.
For example

```
for x in range(2)
     np.savetxt('filex', a1, delimiter=',')
```

Through this I should have 3 files: file0, file1, file2

UPDATE

This works but this only generated one file.

```
for x in range(2)
     np.savetxt('file'+str(x), a1, delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use string formatting

```
for x in range(2)
     np.savetxt('file%s' % x, a1, delimiter=',')
```

Comment: I generate the file, however I only seem to generate only 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in range(2)
     np.savetxt('file' + str(x), a1, delimiter=',')
```

should work

Comment: I generate the file, however I only seem to generate only 1.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? maybe something else affects this part?